# Error converting from varchar value to int value

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

the problem that I have is 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@param4' to data type int.'

I'm new to databases and don't know how to nest SQL injections(I hope i'm using the term correctly).

I saw that you can use CONVERT to convert to int, but I don't know how to nest the SQL "code". 
I've also tried doing it manually in the SQL server management tool. I didn't use parameters and it worked so I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the parameters(as the exception suggests, but I don't know where specifically).

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Books (Name, Author, Category, NrOfPages, Status) " +
                        "VALUES ('@param1', '@param2', '@param3', '@param4', '@param5')", conn);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", "test");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", "test");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", "test");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param4", 0);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param5", "test");
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Name, Author, Category and Status are all varchar(50) and NrOfPages is int.

Comment: You don't need `CONVERT`. You have a syntax error. Remove the `'` around the parameters in your `VALUES()` sub-statement.

Comment: A) Dont bracket parameters with ticks B) Dont use `AddWithValue`

Comment: Also, you need to include the leading `@` character in the `SqlParameter` name string in C#.

Comment: You are actually not using the parameters. Instead, you are using string values like `'@param1'`. The SQL fragment should be `VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5)`, even for varchar parameters.

Comment: Thank you guys, this was helpful. It now works. Also,  @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp what should I use instead of `AddWithValue`? I tried `Add` but c# said it was deprecated.